# When sum of fraction is the same as the fraction made by the sum of numerators and sum of denominators

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, fractions

My students naturally want to add fractions adding numerators and denominators. I say many times it does not rule like this, but is there a (small) set of integers which this rule work? That is

Where is 
$$\{ (x, y, z, t ) \in \mathbb{Z}^4 \, | \, \frac{x}{y} + \frac{z}{t} = \frac{x+z}{y+t}\}$$

Comment: That set is definitely non-empty; try setting $ y = t = 1$ or $y = t = -1$.

Comment: $x=z=0$ also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written as,

$$\frac{xt+yz}{yt} = \frac{x+z}{y+t} \implies xty + y^2z + yzt +xt^2 = ytx + yzt$$

> $$y^2z+xt^2 = 0$$

Comment: Is the reciprocal true? If $y^2z + xt^2=0$, then $\frac{x}{y} + \frac{z}{t} = \frac{x+z}{y+t}$?

Comment: Provided that $y+t \not= 0$ and $yt \not= 0$ i.e, $\color{blue}{y \not=- t, y,t \not=0}$ otherwise we can't divide by those terms.

Answer (score 1):

I got the equation $$y^2z+xt^2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Constructive solution: given a fraction $\frac xy$, choose a non-zero number $k$.  Then define $z=-k^2x$ and $t=ky$, thus
$$\frac zt =\frac{-k^2x}{ky}.$$
Then either way their sum will be $(1-k)\frac xy$.

An example with small numbers would be $x=1$, $y=2$ and $k=2$ which gives
$$\frac12+\frac{-4}{4}=-\frac12.$$

NB: You may even construct more "exotic" ones: $x=1/2$, $y=2/3$ and $k=2$ gives
$$\frac{\frac12}{\frac23}+\frac{-2}{\frac43}=-\frac34$$
either way.
You should also give
$$\frac12+\frac{-2}{2\sqrt2}$$
a try.